# unable to bootstrap ec2 ubuntu instance

Tags: ubuntu, amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, chef

Hi I am trying to bootstrap an ubuntu ec2 instance using knife command line tool, but when ever I run this command

```
knife ec2 server create -x ubuntu --region ap-southeast-1  -i ami-0cdf4965 -S key  --identity-file  ~/key.pem  -G default  -r 'recipe[apt],recipe[apache2],recipe[ntp],recipe[ruby]'
```

I knife throws out an error

```
ERROR: You did not provide a valid 'Image' value
```

and when ever I use -I ami-id it tell use -i instead of -I, but I can bootstrap an instance in us-east region but unable to do it in the ap-southeast region.

Kindly help me out

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you trying to use the same AMI in ap-southeast as us-east?  The machine definitions are only valid for the region in which they were created.

I googled the AMI referenced in the ticket and it's a Ubuntu Quantal release.  Use the Ubuntu [Amazon EC2 AMI Locator](http://cloud-images.ubuntu.com/locator/ec2/) to track down an appropriate AMI and try that out.

Comment: I am using the different ami id which is available in ap-southeast-1 region but still I am getting the same error

Comment: Just now I used this ami id ami-7881cc2a but still getting the same error. Here is the command I ran  knife ec2 server create -x ubuntu --region ap-southeast-1  -image ami-7881cc2a  --identity-file /home/user/key.pem --ebs-size 8  -G default  -r 'recipe[apt],recipe[apache2],recipe[ntp],recipe[ruby]'

Comment: Did you use  `-image` or `--image`?  The error is coming from knife and not Amazon.

Comment: Now I am getting different issue which says key doesn't exists... I am trying to fix since a very long time, I am facing this issue only is ap-southeast-1 region when I try to create a node in US its working fine. Can you help me please???? @Tim Potter

Comment: You most likely need to create a new key for the ap region as key pairs, like AMIs, are not shared across regions.